# Check Access database for datachanges

Tags: vb.net, winforms, ms-access

Working in a VB.Net 3.5 WinForms application, and using Access 2003 (JET 4.0) as a database backend through ADO.Net.

I'd like to check the database for changes, before the application decides to refresh the data from the server. Are there any best practices for this, or should I trust the ADO.Net environment to optimise/handle this?

I was thinking of using a limited log on the server, which gets updated by every change. Pulling this log could tell whether or not a certain table has changed data. Any good?

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is to use a file based cache, which would just invalidate the cache if anything is written to the database.

This won't give you any table specific caching so this isn't the most efficient thinkable cache.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Could you elaborate some more? Is there a cache I could turn on, and do you have any experience in size/performance of this solution?